# What is a zone in the context of SSL?

Tags: ssl, dns, cloudflare

Cloudflair provides this disclaimer:

```
The "Always Use HTTPS" option will only appear if your zone has an active SSL certificate associated with it on Cloudflare.
```

I have just moved a domain over to cloudflair, though the transfer hasn't gone through yet. I don't get the always use https-option and at this point i'm too afraid to ask.

Answer (score 2):

Zone = Domain for our purposes.

If you just signed up the SSL cert likely hasn't issued quite yet.

Just ask our support team if you have a question, our support team is here to answer questions like this.